# Why wont my C code about reversed bits work?

Tags: c, reverse, bit, unsigned-integer

I am working on code to reverse an unsigned int whose bits are the same but in reverse order. My code wont stop running while taking user input. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int reverse_bits(unsigned int n);

int main(void) {
        unsigned int n;
        printf("Enter an unsigned integer: ");
        scanf("%u",&n);
        printf("%u\n",reverse_bits(n));
        return 0;
}

unsigned int reverse_bits(unsigned int n) {
        unsigned int reverse = 0;
        while(n>0) {
                reverse <<= 1;
                if((n & 1) == 1) {
                        reverse = reverse^1;
                }
        }
        return reverse;
}
```

Comment: You never modify `n` inside the loop, so the loop never ends.

Comment: If the input is 1011, do you want output of 1101 (reversed in the four significant bits) or 11010000000000000000000000000000 (reversed in 32 bits, or in some other fixed-size field)? If you only reverse within the significant bits, observe that the reverse of the reverse will not restore the number, as reversing 101100 produces 001101, which is 1101, and then reversing that produces 1011, not the original 101100.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, the while condition is checking whether n is greater than zero. However, inside the loop, there was no operation that modifies the n. So please try using this. It will work.

```
unsigned int reverse_bits(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int reverse = 0;
    while (n>0) {
            reverse <<=1;
            if((n & 1) == 1) {
                    reverse = reverse | 1;
            }
            n=n>>1;

    }
    return reverse;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

as @Mark Benningfield said you forget to modify `n` inside the loop and the

best way to reverse a string is:-

It only runs upto when the leftmost bit is `1`.

```
  unsigned int reverse_bits(unsigned int n) 
    {
      unsigned int reverse = 0;
        int x = 1;
        while ( n > 0 )
        {
            reverse = reverse << 1;
            if ( n & x )
                reverese = reverse | 1;
            n = n >> 1;
        }
        return reverse;
```